# System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException

Tags: c#, exception, csv

I am just trying to upload files to an outbound caller, this used to work fine. I am suddenly experiencing long run times for jobs which usually take less than 10 minutes. The jobs are now failing. Here is the exception that I get. Any help on fixing this is appreciated.

```
Five9 Outbound interface has started
Five9 Outbound has4 to process
Application is starting to process the file: \\pcnfs06\OutboundCallList\campaignfolder\3 day Conservation\conservation.csv
Application is filtering the conservation list
Application is uploading the list to Five9
Application is archiving the File: \\pcnfs06\OutboundCallList\campaignfolder\3 day Conservation\conservation.csv
Application has processed the file: \\pcnfs06\OutboundCallList\campaignfolder\3 day Conservation\conservation.csv
Application is starting to process the file: \\pcnfs06\OutboundCallList\campaignfolder\Invoice Assist\Invoice_Call.csv
Application is filtering the lists
Application is uploading the list to Five9
Five9 Outbound has7 to process
Application is starting to process the file: \\pcnfs06\OutboundCallList\campaignfolder\3 day Conservation\conservation.csv
Five9 Outbound has10 to process
Application is starting to process the file: \\pcnfs06\OutboundCallList\campaignfolder\3 day Conservation\conservation.csv
Max number of errors occured in Retry function for : System.Func`1[System.Object]Exceptions: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Exception]
Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: List "Invoice Assist" doesn't exist.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at CallFive9Service.com.five9.api.WsAdminService.addToList(addToList addToList1)
   at CallFive9Service.CampaignUtil.CampaignUpdater.UpdateToFive9List(List`1 callList, FieldSettings pFS)
   at CallFive9Service.CampaignUtil.CampaignUpdater.ProcessFile(String pFilename, List`1 masterExlusionList, List`1 dnc)
   at CallFive9Service.CampaignUtil.CampaignUpdater.GetFiles(String pRootFolder, String pArchiveFolder)
   at CallFive9Service.CampaignUtil.CampaignUpdater.<>c__DisplayClass2.<StartCampaignUpdate>b__0()
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be something new in the data that comes in your csv files.

Look at the inner exception in your Stack trace:

> SoapException: List "Invoice Assist" doesn't exist.